# Ljung_box test and its interpretation

Tags: python, statistics, autocorrelation, arch, gretl

I don't understand how to obtain a single test statistic Q and a single p-value, as it happens in software like Gretl, instead of getting all the statistics for each lags.

```
lb_test = acorr_ljungbox(residuals, lags=10)
print(lb_test)
```

the output is:

```
      lb_stat  lb_pvalue
1    0.517035   0.472109
2   14.876470   0.000588
3   24.138083   0.000023
4   25.068592   0.000049
5   25.346384   0.000119
6   29.206748   0.000056
7   31.653655   0.000047
8   31.686802   0.000106
9   32.856403   0.000141
10  32.863939   0.000287
```

and I don't really know how to get just one statistics and one p-value with 10 lags. Any clue?

Futhermore, when I estimate a GARCH for the volatility part, Do I need to check the autocorrelation in its residuals or its standardized residuals? Is it ok if I use the ljung box test again?

Thank you so much

I expect an output like this:

```
Ljung-Box Q' = 14,9614,
con p-value = P(Chi-quadro(10) > 14,9614) = 0,133
```